# Compiling IcedTea: JDK home directory could not be found

Tags: 12.04, openjdk, jdk, icedtea

Google Chrome keeps telling me that I need to update icedtea, I tried installing them from terminal, didn't work so I'm installing icedtea and icedtea-web from source, when I do `./configure`  it tells me that fastjar isn't installed so I installed it, then it tells me that gawk isn't installed and I installed it and now it says:

```
checking for a JDK home directory... 
configure: error: "A JDK JDK home directory could not be found.
```

I have openjdk7 installed, how to fix it?

@Ben Hague thank you, your answer fixes the first error, but now i see

```
checking for javah... no
checking for gjavah... no
configure: error: "A Java header generator was not found."
```

Shouldn't javah be bundled with jdk?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Ubuntu puts it a different directory to what `IcedTea` expects. Try

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

Comment: please read my edit